# How to connect a hdb database in kdb q to .q script?

Tags: database, kdb

I want to connect a hdb database inside a kdb `.q` script and query inside a script, not directly on the q prompt.

The code that I now have inside `abc.q` is:

```
h:hopen `:url:port:userid:pwd
h"tables[]"
hclose
```

But this does not seem to work. When I run `q abc.q` on the command line it does not show the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a q process I set the port to `5001` and create some tables:

```
q)\p 5001
q)t1:([] a:1 2 3)
q)t2:([] a:1 2 3)
q)tables[]
`s#`t1`t2
```

`abc.q` contains:

```
h:hopen `:localhost:5001
h"tables[]"
hclose h
exit 0
```

Then running `q abc.q` I see:

```
KDB+ 4.0 2022.10.26 Copyright (C) 1993-2022 Kx Systems
w64/ 8(24)core 16225MB *** spectre *** EXPIRE *** *** KOD #***

`s#`t1`t2
```

Comment: Thanks this works, to send the same as en email without using qmail is possible?